# Is there a way to create an iBeacon region that also functions as a geofence?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ibeacon, geofencing

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didEnterRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
//code for adjusting pins location when user re-enters its radius
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didExitRegion:(CLRegion *)region
{
//code for adding pin to map
}
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didStartMonitoringForRegion:(CLRegion        *)region
{

}

- (CLRegion*)dictToRegion:(NSDictionary*)dictionary
{
NSString *identifier = [dictionary valueForKey:@"identifier"];
CLLocationDegrees latitude = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"latitude"] doubleValue];
CLLocationDegrees longitude =[[dictionary valueForKey:@"longitude"] doubleValue];
CLLocationCoordinate2D centerCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(latitude, longitude);
CLLocationDistance regionRadius = [[dictionary valueForKey:@"radius"] doubleValue];

if(regionRadius >_locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance)
{
    regionRadius =_locationManager.maximumRegionMonitoringDistance;
}

NSString *version = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
CLRegion * region =nil;

if([version floatValue] >= 7.0f) //for iOS7
{
    region =  [[CLCircularRegion alloc] initWithCenter:centerCoordinate
                                                radius:regionRadius
                                            identifier:identifier];
}
else // iOS 7 below
{
    region = [[CLRegion alloc] initCircularRegionWithCenter:centerCoordinate
                                                     radius:regionRadius
                                                 identifier:identifier];
}
return  region;
}
```

So I am trying to make it so that when an iBeacon leaves the region being monitored(which is always the area around the users phone) it also creates a map annotation/pin, thereby marking its last known location. Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

Comment: are you trying to display the pin on a map on your phone?  If so this really has very little to do with iBeacons... you just write code to put a pin on a map at the phone's current location.  The only connection to iBeacons is that you trigger this to happen when you leave the region.

Answer (score 1):

An iBeacon is in effect a geofence.  You define a `CLBeaconRegion` and then monitor for region entry/exits as you do with `CLCircularRegion`.  Unlike `CLCircularRegion`, a `CLBeaconRegion` is defined in terms of the iBeacons *UUID* and optionally its *major* and *minor* values.

You will receive a call to your delegate's `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` method when the iBeacon is visible/no longer visible - It is described in the [Location and Maps Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/RegionMonitoring/RegionMonitoring.html)

You don't get the beacon's location, but you can capture the device's GPS location when you exit the region as an approximate location to where the beacon was last seen.  Once you have that, then creating a map annotation is trivial.

Comment: I believe Apple has extended support for iBeacons in the location manager in iOS 8, and you now CAN tie a beacon to a specific location and create location updates based on beacons. (My business partner got into WWDC this year but I didn't, and I haven't gotten to that session yet.)